# Problem with jQuery setdate after upgrade

Tags: jquery, datepicker, upgrade

I have the following code:

```
<input id="aanschafdatum" type="text" name="aanschafdatum" size="40" value="" />
<input id="sel_aanschafdatum" type="hidden" value="12-05-2011" />

$(document).ready(function() {
    var selected_date = document.getElementById("sel_aanschafdatum").value;
    loadDatepicker('#aanschafdatum', selected_date );
});

 function loadDatepicker(id, selected_date) {
     if (selected_date === undefined) {
         selected_date = "";
     }
     $(function() {
         $(id).datepicker();
     });
     if (selected_date !== '') {
         $(id).datepicker("setDate", selected_date);
     }
 }
```

This code works fine, the current date "12-05-2011" will be set in the datepicker. But after upgrading to the latest version of jQuery it does not work anymore. Only if I remove the `document.ready` from:

```
var selected_date = document.getElementById("sel_aanschafdatum").value;
loadDatepicker('#aanschafdatum', selected_date );
```

it works.

I have tested it with [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MgWNv/3/). With jQuery 1.4.4 it works fine; with jQuery 1.5.2 it does not set the current value.

Hope someone can help, thanks in advance.

Edwin

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong jQuery "syntax", probably in the newer versions they don't forgive such thing anymore.

Inside the function `loadDatepicker` you nest some code inside `$(function() {}` block - this is wrong.

It should be the other way around meaning the `$(function() {}` block should nest functions you want to run. As you already have this code in the context of `$(document).ready` just remove the `$(function() {` and you're all good:

```
function loadDatepicker(id, selected_date) {
     if (selected_date === undefined) {
         selected_date = "";
     }

     $(id).datepicker();

     if (selected_date !== '') {
         $(id).datepicker("setDate", selected_date);
     }
 }
```

Updated jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/MgWNv/5/

Comment: @eme cheers and welcome to Stack Overflow, if my answer solved your problem please mark it as Accepted by clicking the V icon to the left - this way people will know this question is solved.